# Generate report pipeline from the raw data in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, etl

I have a bunch of CSV files (>10000 files) in the S3 bucket and for eeach CSV
file I would like to do some cleaning, and data grouping. After the process I would like to save the report in another S3 bucket.

I already have a Python script that run the whole process but currently it is pretty dumb, running a for loop. I would like to run the whole thing in parallel. Would like to know what is the best practice.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to look at Apache Spark, you can run a "spark job" using AWS Glue, I would think it would do the job you probably need

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I would take a look at the PySpark and AWS Glue. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually I have another question. Would it be cheaper/more efficient to run ETL using AWS Glue or multiple Lambda function?

Comment: Depends on the task, also Lambdas has a max timeout of 15 minutes.